# How do I keep second monitor (HDTV) from auto-disabling in XP when it is turned off?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, hdtv

I have a new 32" TV that I hooked up to the HDMI port on the back of my video card to use as a second monitor.  I used an HDMI/DVI cable to hook it to the TV, and whenever I turn my TV off, XP disables the device tied to the TV so each time I want to use the TV as the monitor, I have to go into my display properties and enable it; it gets pretty annoying.

How do I turn this 'feature' off? -- I have an NVidia card should it be specific to the nvidia control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently discovered the answer to this question by accident.  (Probably a few days ago)

Right click your desktop -> NVidia Control Panel
Go to 'Setup multiple displays'
click 'My display is not shown in the list' (even if it is, click this)
Click Rigorous display detection; it may ask if you want to enable the TV because it couldn't find any more displays...click yes.
Click OK and it should ask you to restart.  Let it all restart and it should quit turning that display off afterwards.