# "Virtual" monitor on a PC which has no real monitor?

Tags: windows, display

Is there any way to create a 'virtual monitor' on a PC that has no real monitor plugged in?
So that I can connect to it using an app such as TeamViewer.

If I run a virtual machine, I will not be able to work with the "real" OS.
Also I've found some things related to it: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/553749/make-winxp-believe-that-there-is-a-second-monitor-ati-radeon-mobility-9000) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/123390/how-do-i-keep-second-monitor-hdtv-from-auto-disabling-in-xp-when-it-is-turned/128839#128839) .
But they're both for connecting SECOND 'virtual' monitor, and they're working only with ATI/NVidia graphics adapters. I've no such adapter (my video is 'onboard'), and I'd like to find an 'universal' way for doing it, which is independent of what graphics adapter you use.

(Moderators: Also I've found many questions which are alike my question. But they are not similar, because they were about creating a 'virtual monitor' to a PC that already has a real monitor plugged in)

Is there any way or program to do it?

Comment: what OS? I think most remote access software should allow this as far as I understand with a onboard video device

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008. But I think OS has no matter here.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04.01 i had Teamviewer 7
Remotely beeing conected i removed it and installed Teamviewer 9. Now i cant anymore connect except when i connect while monitor is connected once for a second- only after that. So im not using that computer becouse if this new somekind of bug.

Answer (score 5):

Using a monitor is not mandatory.
You need it while configuring your computer, but after the initial configuration you can unplug it. To access your computer from the network /LAN or internet/, you can use a lot of applications:

- Remote Desktop, included in any version of windows
- VNC *
- TeamViewer *
- PcAnywhere /if it still exists/

** Please note that those applications need to be launched in an user session, so you won't have the possibility to log-in to your computer unless you execute them as WindowsService.

I always prefer remote desktop for reliability and security

Comment: You mean I can use TeamViewer to connect to my screen without monitor, if once I had connected a monitor to it??

Comment: well, you need the monitor to install the OS and TeamViewer itself. Please note that TW is not reliable if a user session is not open (you have to login to your computer to use it). a workaround for this is using "autologin function" in windows, but that's not a good idea (mainly for security reasons)

Comment: but if I use some screen-shoter and get an empty picture, does it mean that my server has never been connected to a monitor??

Comment: no, maybe that you don't have a console session